# Where's my Zen Garden?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies, android

I finished a whole first adventure of Plants vs Zombies, but NO ZEN GARDEN. I have Quickplay, some awards, a key to Crazy Dave's shop, but no Zen Garden. Is it because you have to have a certain device to get the Garden? I'm confused. Do you unlock it in the second adventure? That I would understand. I even defeated the Zombot on the very last level! Do you need the Yeti Zombie to get it?

Comment: Which platform are you playing this on, and which version of the game do you have?

Comment: I was very disappointed to see this as well.. The Zen Garden was actually the reason I've downloaded the game.

Answer (score 14):

The Zen garden is missing on Android.
It's available on the PC and iOS versions.

Comment: @Zoe Please mark this answer as the correct one to give credit to the author of it.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.popcap.pvz_na&hl=en) has all the features included in the desktop game. If you bought your game from Google Play, update it and Zen Garden would be available.

Answer (score 2):

I searched the internet and found a possible reason: if you downloaded it with the Humble Bundle for Android, there's no Zen Garden, as the lasts updates aren't available in the Humble Bundle library.
It seems that the Humble Bundle team didn't want to promote in-app purchases added in last updates.

Comment: That would probably defy the purpose of having bought the "full" version before